# TypeScript: how to make keyof typeof to return keys and avoid circular reference

Tags: typescript, typeof, keyof

For the code below, I'd like to extract the keys of `routes`.

```js
type Route = {
  url: string
  auth: boolean
}

type Routes = Record<string, Route>

const routes: Routes = {
    add: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: false
    },
    delete: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: true
    }
}
```

If I define keys as this:

```js
type RouteKeys = keyof typeof routes
```

the RouteKeys transpiles to `string` because infers from `Record<string>`, fine - but I'd like it to be `'add' | 'delete'`.

When I try:

```js
type Routes = Record<keyof typeof routes, Route>
```

then I receive a TypeScript error "Type alias Routes circularily references itself" which is fair too.

I understand if I define:

```js
type RouteKeys = 'add' | 'delete'
```

and assign it to Routes it will work, but this will force me to manually make changes to type every time there is a new route. Alternatively I am forced to give up on "Route" type in Routes which is not ideal as I work further on this type conditionally.

Is there a way to obtain keys and keep the "Routes" type without hardcoding them anywhere but also keep the Route type values specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to guarantee that the values of the properties of `routes` are all assignable to `Route`:

```
const routes = {
    add: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: false
    },
    delete: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: true
    }
} satisfies { [k: string]: Route }
```

That breaks the potential circularity so now you can define `Routes` in terms of `typeof routes`:

```
type Routes = Record<keyof typeof routes, Route>
```

In this version, `routes` has a type somewhat narrower than `Routes` because the values might be subtypes of `Route`.  If you need `routes` to be exactly of type `Routes` you can always rename it out of the way to start and then copy the result:

```
const _routes = {
    add: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: false
    },
    delete: {
        url: '/comment',
        auth: true
    }
} satisfies { [k: string]: Route }        
type Routes = Record<keyof typeof _routes, Route>    
const routes: Routes = _routes;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3gKCjqCBOANgFxQDOw+AlgHYDm2uAhkgBakBGcchETNmAL6ZMAYzg0KUAPr5EyMlDRZcUJgBN1pFatwESUAOQB6cQFszEGsEMAaRrrVtSAMyaEyEB1EH3V6iF5kbW9VfVITc0trO1DmZyhKBC9VYUFyJmAqMhcqCEV0KABtAGtSCmp6AF1SeCRoYRFQSFh5fKVYCHF8dQAeEogQOBdE8AhhmTl6sltW+oA+EXFJYCgphVq2xTRZLYBuIA)

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for